# Template Inherited Classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to make a wrapper class for generic data (POD or objects) that can be represented in a collection. Basically, I have a large set of data of varying types that I need to add other data to (like read/write times) but I would like to be able to represent this data in an STL container. Rough example:

```
class Base
{
    int lastUpdate;
    void SomeMember();
}

template<class T>
class Object : public Base
{
    T data;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> data;
    data.push_back(new Object<int>());
    data.push_back(new Object<OtherClass>());
}
```

Is something like the above possible?

Comment: Did you try to compile it?

Comment: Is it not working for you or what is the problem you're having? Also, don't forget about using smart pointers (e.g., `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`).

Comment: [Something like the above is indeed possible](http://ideone.com/TEErPC). Why didn't you try it?

Comment: Outside of leaking memory, this is fine. Otherwise, it's unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but I have the feeling that the `Object` class turns out to be completely unnecessary in the long run.

Comment: Had an issue else where in my code. Should have compiled my code first. Thanks for the (smart) pointers guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is possible. Your approach looks right as well. You basically define a common base class, and a templated derived class (as shown in your code example).

The only thing missing from your example are the semicolons after the class definitions.